How can I fix the Type Error related to 'params', npm run build failed
npm run build failed terminal
.next/types/app/(course)/courses/[courseId]/chapters/[chapterId]/page.ts:34:29
Type error: Type '{ params: { courseId: string; chapterId: string; }; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'PageProps'.
  Types of property 'params' are incompatible.
    Type '{ courseId: string; chapterId: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<any>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]

  32 |
  33 | // Check the prop type of the entry function
> 34 | checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<TEntry['default']>, 'default'>>()
     |                             ^
  35 |
  36 | // Check the arguments and return type of the generateMetadata function
  37 | if ('generateMetadata' in entry) {

in here when i try to run the npm run build command it show this error
page.tsx
export interface PageProps {
  params?: Promise<SegmentParams>
  searchParams?: Promise<any>
}
export interface LayoutProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode

  params?: Promise<SegmentParams>
}

I try add Promise<> but still not working.
